# Django readonly field only on change, but not when creating

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a `Team` model whit `players` ManyToManyField, and I want to be able to add `Player`s to a new team when created, but not able to modify it after created.

If I make the `players` field readonly like this:

```
# admin.py
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    readonly_fields = ['players']

admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

I will not be able to add players to a new `Team`.
How can I make the `players` field "readonly after created" or something like that?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to override [`get_readonly_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) method of your admin class.

```
# admin.py
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    ...

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj: #This is the case when obj is already created i.e. it's an edit
            return ['players']
        else:
            return []
```