# How to make non-editable fields appear when creating objects in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with a non-editable field in my models file.

```
class Table(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=40, editable=False)
```

In my admin site, when updating existing Table objects, I can't edit the label. That is fine, this is exactly what I want with this constraint. However, when trying to create an object using the admin site, the field is still hidden, so I can only create Table objects using the shell.

How can I make this field appear only on creation, but on updates, it will be read-only? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing Edit to editable=False Fields in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128240/allowing-edit-to-editable-false-fields-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 4):

**Approach 1**

Make *label* field presented on creation but completely remove it while updating. We will be using [ModelAdmin.get_exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_exclude) and [ModelAdmin.get_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) hooks to accomplish this.

```
## models.py
class Table(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=40) # remove editable option

## admin.py
@admin.register(Table)
class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    non_editable_fields = ['label']
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        defaults = super().get_exclude(request, obj=obj) or ()
        if obj: # if we are updating an object
            defaults = (*defaults, *self.non_editable_fields)
        return defaults or None

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        defaults = super().get_fields(request, obj=obj)
        if obj: # if we are updating an object
            defaults = tuple(f for f in defaults if f not in self.non_editable_fields)
        return defaults
```

**Approach 2**

Make *label* field presented on both creation and update but make it read only while updating. django admin provides a hook for this functioanlity and it is called `ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields`. You can find the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields).

So we can write the following code to create a field which can be presented/added when creating an object but can not be edited any further despite set value is being displayed(through admin site).

```
## models.py
class Table(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=40) # remove editable option

## admin.py
@admin.register(Table)
class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        defaults = super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj=obj)
        if obj:  # if we are updating an object
            defaults = tuple(defaults) + ('label', )  # make sure defaults is a tuple
        return defaults
```

**Bonus for Approach 2**

Also if you have multiple fields on that table you can use [fields property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) to set the ordering(read only fields which are not specifically ordered will be shown at the end of the field list). Down side for this ordering approach is that you have to remember to reflect model changes to `fields` property every time you make a change in your model.

Comment: Thats not what he asked

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [**`readonly_fields`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in **`admin.py`** file

```
class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('label',)

admin.site.register(Table, TableAdmin)
```

Comment: Once again, the field cannot be added when creating new objects.

Comment: but wouldn't that make the field editable? That is something I don't want.

Comment: It won't be editable if you set that field in `readonly_fields`

Comment: It won't be editable using the admin, but it can still be edited using the shell.

Comment: Through Django shell, you can do whatever you want. You can't  restrict edit actions. (You could even change the **`PK`** value of a model instance through django-shell)

Comment: Oh thats interesting. Am I misunderstanding what is said in this link then - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#editable ? It says it also skips model validation.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee Yes, you're. The validation process has no role in your context

Comment: Nope, even then, the field is not editable on the creation form. Its only read-only, which means its empty on the creation form.