# django admin readonly_fields = 'some_field' but create or add cannot edit the same

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the Django admin, I have

```
    readonly_fields = 'some_field'
```

However, creating or adding cannot edit the field.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Clarify your query again properly.

Comment: You misunderstand, I mean, admin can create any field, but to limit the editorial function of some fields, readonly_fields will result in can not be entered when creating, I mean in the admin interface, not through the api or django shell

Comment: I got it myself，tank you for your answer

Comment: def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
  if obj is None:
   return ()
  return self.readonly_fields

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are asking, but does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613559/django-readonly-field-only-on-change-but-not-when-creating

Comment: @MaMars Put your answer in Answer box and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None): 
    if obj is None:
        return () 
    return self.readonly_fields
```

(the answer, per the original poster @Ma_Mars in the question comment [django admin readonly_fields = 'some_field' but create or add cannot edit the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544381/django-admin-readonly-fields-some-filed-but-create-or-add-can-not-edit-the-s#comment84086533_48544381) )